# System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission is thrown for Scripting.FileSystemObject

Tags: c#, filesystemobject

I have added `C:\Windows\System32\scrrun.dll` as a reference to my web forms application in order to use Interop.Scripting.dll.
It works fine with my local computer.

When I load the application to my production server, I get "`System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission`" exception message, and there is no furher or detailed exception message.The excepiton is thrown for the following line:

```
Scripting.FileSystemObject fso = new Scripting.FileSystemObject();
```

Since it is a permission issue, I have also used impersonation in my web.config with Administrator credentials of the server. Bu it did not work.

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="Administrator" password="xxxxxx" />
```

Any help or clue is really welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

close your visual studio and reopen it using admin privilege. Just right click and click on run as administrator. May this will work for you.